# Property 'date' does not exist on type 'EmployeeScheduleExceptionModel'.ts(2339) but it does on the base class that it inherits from

Tags: typescript, inheritance, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a TS project with the following `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "include": ["src*"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2021",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["es6"],
        "declaration": false,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./",
        "removeComments": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "paths": {
            "@shared/*": ["./src/shared/*"]
        },
        "types": ["node"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    }
}
```

and `tsconfig.test.json`

```
{
    "include": ["src*"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2021",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["es6"],
        "declaration": false,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./",
        "removeComments": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "paths": {
            "@shared/*": ["./src/shared/*"]
        },
        "types": ["node", "jest"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    }
}
```

and in the `src` folder

I have the type `EmployeeScheduleExceptionModel` that extends `ScheduleExceptionModel` and `implements` `ScheduleException`

```
export interface ScheduleException {
    date: Date;
    start: Date;
    end: Date;
    isOn: boolean;
    lastModifiedDateTime: Date;
}


export class ScheduleExceptionModel implements ScheduleException {
    public date: Date;
    public start: Date;
    public end: Date;
    public isOn: boolean;
    public lastModifiedDateTime: Date;

    public constructor(scheduleException: ScheduleException) {
        this.date = new Date(scheduleException.date);
        this.start = new Date(scheduleException.start);
        this.end = new Date(scheduleException.end);
        this.isOn = scheduleException.isOn;
        this.lastModifiedDateTime = new Date(
            scheduleException.lastModifiedDateTime
        );
    }
}

export class EmployeeScheduleExceptionModel
    extends ScheduleExceptionModel
    implements EmployeeScheduleException
{
    public employeeID: string;
}
```

in the `test` folder I have `employee-schedule-exception-model-test.spec.ts`

```
describe('EmployeeScheduleExceptionModel tests', function () {

    it('toDynamo success test', async function () {
        const schedule = {
            lastModifiedDateTime: new Date('2022-03-02T07:46:24.809Z'),
            employeeID: '123',
            date: new Date('2022-03-02T07:46:24.809Z'),
            start: new Date('2022-03-02T07:46:24.809Z'),
            end: new Date('2022-03-02T07:46:24.809Z'),
            isOn: true,
        };
        const scheduleModel = new EmployeeScheduleExceptionModel(schedule);
        const expected = {
            LastModifiedDateTime:
                scheduleModel.lastModifiedDateTime.toISOString(),
            EmployeeID: scheduleModel.employeeID,
            Date: scheduleModel.date.toISOString(),
            Start: scheduleModel.start.toISOString(),
            End: scheduleModel.end.toISOString(),
            IsOn: scheduleModel.isOn,
        };
        expect(scheduleModel.toDynamo()).toEqual(expected);
    });
}
```

`Property 'date' does not exist on type 'EmployeeScheduleExceptionModel'.ts(2339)`

I am getting this error in vscode for all the inherited properties on `scheduleModel` in the last code snippet so `scheduleModel.employeeID` is fine

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat clear with all the models listed that you're using. However, there seems to be some missing information about the `EmployeeScheduleException` that is implemented on the model `EmployeeScheduleExceptionModel`. Can you please update your question with that model?

Anyway, coming to your model initialization, I notice a few concerns over the types being passed into the constructor of `EmployeeScheduleExceptionModel`. The type this constructor accepts is of type `ScheduleException`. However, while constructing a new instance of that model, the object being passed contains a property that is not on the `ScheduleException`. Please see the comment made inline.

```
describe('EmployeeScheduleExceptionModel tests', function () {

it('toDynamo success test', async function () {
    const schedule = {
        lastModifiedDateTime: new Date('2022-03-02T07:46:24.809Z'),
        employeeID: '123', `// not available on the type`
        date: new Date('2022-03-02T07:46:24.809Z'),
        start: new Date('2022-03-02T07:46:24.809Z'),
        end: new Date('2022-03-02T07:46:24.809Z'),
        isOn: true,
    }; // object is not strongly typed.
    // above object passed below.
    const scheduleModel = new EmployeeScheduleExceptionModel(schedule);
    const expected = {
        LastModifiedDateTime:
            scheduleModel.lastModifiedDateTime.toISOString(),
        EmployeeID: scheduleModel.employeeID,
        Date: scheduleModel.date.toISOString(),
        Start: scheduleModel.start.toISOString(),
        End: scheduleModel.end.toISOString(),
        IsOn: scheduleModel.isOn,
    };
    expect(scheduleModel.toDynamo()).toEqual(expected);
});
```

}

Below is the updated code that I tested on my local in visual studio code and I do not see any errors.

```
export interface ScheduleException {
  date: Date;
  start: Date;
  end: Date;
  isOn: boolean;
  lastModifiedDateTime: Date;
}


export class ScheduleExceptionModel implements ScheduleException {
  public date: Date;
  public start: Date;
  public end: Date;
  public isOn: boolean;
  public lastModifiedDateTime: Date;

  public constructor(scheduleException: ScheduleException) {
    this.date = new Date(scheduleException.date);
    this.start = new Date(scheduleException.start);
    this.end = new Date(scheduleException.end);
    this.isOn = scheduleException.isOn;
    this.lastModifiedDateTime = new Date(
        scheduleException.lastModifiedDateTime
    );
  }
}

export class EmployeeScheduleExceptionModel
extends ScheduleExceptionModel
{
 public employeeID: string;
}


const schedule: ScheduleException = {
 lastModifiedDateTime: new Date('2022-03-02T07:46:24.809Z'),
 // employeeID: '123',
 date: new Date('2022-03-02T07:46:24.809Z'),
 start: new Date('2022-03-02T07:46:24.809Z'),
 end: new Date('2022-03-02T07:46:24.809Z'),
 isOn: true,
};
const scheduleModel = new EmployeeScheduleExceptionModel(schedule);

const expected = {
 LastModifiedDateTime:
    scheduleModel.lastModifiedDateTime.toISOString(),
 EmployeeID: scheduleModel.employeeID,
 Date: scheduleModel.date.toISOString(),
 Start: scheduleModel.start.toISOString(),
 End: scheduleModel.end.toISOString(),
 IsOn: scheduleModel.isOn,
};
```

Please provide more information or comment if something is unclear so that we all can help.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answer. the error is in the test project not the main project. the tests are not strongly typed because when I do strongly type them it says i.e. for     
```
const schedule: EmployeeScheduleException = {
        lastModifiedDateTime:....
```
it would say that `lastModifiedDateTime` is not defined on `EmployeeScheduleException` but EmployeeScheduleException inherits from `ScheduleException` which defines `lastModifiedDateTime`  

And that is what I want to fix
I want my test project not to complain about inherited properties